# Using ranges-v3 to implement DFS

Tags: c++, range-v3

I'm interested in using range-v3 to build and query linear quadtree data structures. I've been able to successfully use range-v3 to construct a linear quadtree data structure using existing views in the library. I'm excited to be able to express query logic as a view adaptor since you can iterate through nodes in the quadtree via advancing a RandomAccessIterator of the derived range, which conveniently helps separate out query behavior from the quadtree's structure.

My view adaptor has a single argument: a user-defined lambda predicate function that is used to evaluate a node and determine whether to step-in or step-out. Stepping in results in evaluating children nodes whereas stepping out results in visiting the next sibling (or potentially the node's parent's next sibling) until either a leaf node is successfully evaluated or we "exit" through the root node. (You can think of this as a DFS pattern.)

Thus, we are able to define this range in terms of a RandomAccessIterator (from the derived range) and a Sentinel (as opposed to another Iterator).

Here's some trimmed-down code that shows the overall structure. (My apologies if there is missing member data/structure):

```cpp
template<typename Rng, typename Fun>
class quadtree_query_view
  : public ranges::view_adaptor<quadtree_query_view<Rng, Fun>, Rng>
{
    friend ranges::range_access;

    using base_iterator_t = ranges::iterator_t<Rng>;

    ranges::semiregular_t<Fun> fun;
    uint tree_depth;

    struct query_termination_adaptor : public ranges::adaptor_base
    {
        query_termination_adaptor() = default;
        query_termination_adaptor(uint tree_depth) : tree_depth(tree_depth) {};

        uint tree_depth;

        uint end(quadtree_query_view const&) {
            return tree_depth;
        }
    };

    struct query_adaptor : public ranges::adaptor_base
    {
        query_adaptor() = default;
        query_adaptor(ranges::semiregular_t<Fun> const& fun) : fun(fun) {};

        ranges::semiregular_t<Fun> fun;

        bool exited = false;
        uint current_node_depth = 0;

        base_iterator_t begin(quadtree_query_view const& rng) {
            return ranges::begin(rng.base());
        }

        // TODO: implement equal?
        // TODO: implement empty?

        auto read(base_iterator_t const& it) const 
        {
            return *it; // I'm not concerned about the value returned by this range yet.
        }

        CONCEPT_REQUIRES(ranges::RandomAccessIterator<base_iterator_t>())
        void next(base_iterator_t& it ){
            if (fun(*it)) { // Step in
                // Advance base iterator (step in)
                // Increment current_node_depth
            } else {  // Step out
                // Advance base iterator (step out)
                // Set "exited = true" if stepping out past root node.
                // Decrement current_node_depth
            }
        }
    };

public:
    quadtree_query_view() = default;

    quadtree_query_view(Rng&& rng, uint tree_depth, Fun fun)
      : quadtree_query_view::view_adaptor{std::forward<Rng>(rng)}
      , tree_depth(tree_depth)
      , fun(std::move(fun))
    {}

    query_adaptor begin_adaptor() const {
        return {std::move(fun)};
    }

    query_termination_adaptor end_adaptor() const {
        return {tree_depth};
    }
};
```

I'm trying to figure out the last few steps to complete this implementation:

- My range does not satisfy the `Range` concept due to `WeaklyEqualityComparable` requirement not being implemented for my iterator/sentinel pair. What's the best way for going upon doing this?
- Do I need to implement the `equal` member method for the `query_adaptor`? What do the two iterator arguments correspond to?
- I'm assuming that I need to implement the `empty` member method for `query_adaptor`. Is this where the query exit criteria logic would go? Based on the documentation, the segment argument needs to be a type associated with the sentinel. Is this the same type that is returned by `query_termination_adaptor::end()`, e.g., a `uint`? Or does this need to be another type?

Thanks for any insights you can share. I'm really stoked to see ranges be incorporated into C++20!

Answer (score 0):

Ah.

I was able to solve my problem by using `default_sentinel`. Since `query_adaptor` is meant to start at the root node and iterate in a single direction, I can remove `end_adaptor` and `query_termination_adaptor` all-together. I only had to implement a `bool equal(default_sentinel) const { ... }` method for the adaptor where I am able to determine if query exit criteria is met.

I'm still not sure why trying to implement a custom sentinel type caused issue for me. However, it did't provide any additional functionality over `default_sentinel`, other than owning `tree_depth`.